# Is there a way to create an alert based on results from Read API in ionic?

Tags: api, ionic-framework, notifications, alerts

I’m using an ionic app and I’m trying to create alerts based on the return from an API I’ve made in PHP. The api runs constantly via a PHP server and checks if anymore rows have been added from MySQL database every few seconds.

I would like to be able to create an alert/ push notification in ionic triggered when the results read from the API is >= 1. Please let me know if there’s any advice for me.

PS I’m aware this method is not the most efficient way but avoiding onesignal/ Firebase push notification

Comment: How will this method work if app is closed?

Comment: At the minute it’s just a proof of concept so all I have to show is the alert showing in the open app. There is also a background plugin for ionic/Cordova that enables background tasks to run which could potentially be used if I were to further develop the concept